# Having a hard time grasping *= function

Tags: python

So if

```
balance = int(100)
balance *= 0.05
```

since balance is mutable should'nt that equal to 105? instead i just get 5.

and if i add another line of code such as

```
balance = int(100)
balance *= 0.05
balance *= 0.05
```

the output would be 0.25, essentially my variable is not carrying over and im just multiplying the end outcome to 5%

if i add

```
balance= int(100)
balance *= 0.05 + balance
```

i get 10005

I thought += or *= function could be used for an equation that would take a variable, do the equation then carry over the variable + the outcome as the new variable.

How do i do that for a multi step equation.

Comment: `balance *= 1.05` would give you `105`. You're not adding 5%, you're removing 95%. Also `int(100)` is a bit pointless, just write the integer literal `100`.

Comment: `balance *= 0.05` means *"retrieve the value of the balance variable, multiply that value by 0.05, and put the result back into the balance variable."*

Comment: `balance *= 0.05` is just shorthand for `balance = balance * 0.05`

Comment: And `balance *= 0.05 + balance` means `balance = balance * (0.05 + balance)`, which is not what you want.

Comment: "since balance is mutable" huh? `balance` is an `int`, and `int` objects are immutable...

Answer (score 6):

```
balance = int(100)
balance *= 0.05
```

is the same as

```
balance = int(100)
balance = balance * 0.05
```

Wouldn't you say that that's 5, not 105?

A *= B is just a shorthand for A = A * B.

Your third example is the same as:

```
balance= int(100)
balance = balance * (0.05 + balance)
```

Again, you're getting what I would think you'd expect from this code.

BTW, you don't need the int().  100 by itself is a literal value of type 'int'.  So the most concise way to state your first code block is:

```
 balance = 100 * .05
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for saying this but you have to first under the python or any programming language basics.

'+' is addition sigh

'*' is multiplication sign

A = 2 + 3
gives 5 as answer, and
A = 2 * 3 will give 6 as answer.

Secondly, '+=' , '*=' are shorthand where the operation's first value is the same space where you want to save the result.

like

A = 5

and want to add 3 in this same 'A'

A = A + 3  or can also be written as A += 3,

similarly for multiplication

A = 100

A = 100 * 0.05 can also be written as A *= 0.05

it will give A as 5

So, good luck.